# Deserializing JSON Class with multiple Objects with different types

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to deserialize the following string output to json in csharp.

Now the Problem is, that there are multiple objects that i dont know how to access.
My endgoal would be to access for example just the twitch object.

How would my Jsonclass need to look like?
Thanks in advance.

```
[
    {
        "type": "battlenet",
        "id": "zzzz#25589",
        "name": "zzzz#25589",
        "visibility": 1,
        "friend_sync": false,
        "show_activity": true,
        "verified": true
    },
    {
        "type": "steam",
        "id": "45356364364564",
        "name": "zzzz",
        "visibility": 1,
        "friend_sync": false,
        "show_activity": true,
        "verified": true
    },
    {
        "type": "twitch",
        "id": "4353454353453",
        "name": "zzzzz",
        "visibility": 1,
        "friend_sync": false,
        "show_activity": true,
        "verified": true
    },
    {
        "type": "youtube",
        "id": "xxxxx-xxxxxx",
        "name": "Salt",
        "visibility": 1,
        "friend_sync": false,
        "show_activity": true,
        "verified": true
    }
]
```

Comment: You'd have to deserialize the whole lot into an array, then search it for the object you want.

Comment: You removed the json contents. I can imagine because of privacy concerns. It's still visible via the edit history. You might want to delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is a JSON array of objects. You have to parse it to an array or List :

Your object :

```
public class SomeObject
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("visibility")]
    public int Visibility { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("friend_sync")]
    public bool FriendSync { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("show_activity")]
    public bool ShowActivity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("verified")]
    public bool Verified { get; set; }
}
```

Parsing :
`var resultList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SomeObject>>(jsonstring);`

Then, just search for the `twitch` object :

```
resultList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.type == "twitch")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm on the wrong path right now,

but since they've got all the same attributes why don't you try implement an Interface/Superclass and use Reflection to get the correct Type according to the value in "type" ?

To get the instance:

```
public object GetInstance(string typeString)
{         
     Type t = Type.GetType(typeString); 
     return  Activator.CreateInstance(t);         
}
```